# VBA code number formatting

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Worksheet image]

With the below code I am trying to format cells when certain names appear in a drop down list(cell C4) and format these specific cells in Range G9:N9. But when I run the code it converts all numbers into percents appose to differentiating between the two formatting styles (Percent and General). Can anyone help?

```
Sub LetsMakeThisWork()
    With Worksheets("Geo")
        If C4 = V2 Or C4 = x2 Or C4 = AB2 Or C4 = AD2 Or C4 = AG2 Or C4 = AM2 Or C4 = AO2 Or C4 = AQ2 Or C4 = AU2 Or C4 = AW2 Then
            ActiveCell.Range("G9:N9").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Range("G9:N9").NumberFormat = "General"    
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data? The `If` statement holds little to no meaning for us.

Comment: Your IF statements with OR mean that if any of them is TRUE it will format everything in the given range to %, if you show us what your data looks like, you will get a better answer...

Comment: Also where do you get the values for C4, V2, X2, etc.. as the way they are in your IF statement, VBA will think that they are variables and not Cells or Ranges...

Comment: @Henry That image doesn't help at all. We're missing cell references and it has a lot of distracting information that we don't need. Please include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hopefully you are using `Option Explicit` and have defined `C4` etc. elsewhere in your code. Otherwise you are just testing that the default values of implicitly declared empty variables are the same -- which they will be. Also -- qualifying `Range` by `ActiveCell` is weird and probably not what you intend (unless you know that `ActiveCell` is `A1` on the desired sheet).

Answer (score 1):

In context, you intend `C4, V2` etc. to be a cell references but VBA is interpreting them as variables. The fact that your code runs at all in that case implies that you are not using `Option Explicit`, which you really should use in VBA. What seems to be happening is that you are implicitly creating empty variables in the process of testing them for equality. Any two empty variables are equal, hence the first clause of the `If` statement is always run. Corrected, but not tested, your code should (I think) look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LetsMakeThisWork()
    Dim C4 As Range
    With Worksheets("Geo")
        Set C4 = .Range("C4")
        If C4.Value = .Range("RV2").Value Or C4.Value = .Range("X2").Value Or _
            C4.Value = .Range("AB2").Value Or C4.Value = .Range("AD2").Value Or _
            C4.Value = .Range("AG2").Value Or C4.Value = .Range("AM2").Value Or _
            C4.Value = .Range("AO2").Value Or C4.Value = .Range("AQ2").Value Or _
            C4.Value = .Range("AU2").Value Or C4.Value = .Range("AW2").Value Then
            .Range("G9:N9").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Else
            .Range("G9:N9").NumberFormat = "General"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```